# ByVal Target with multiple ranges written simpler in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

We are trying to link the value of specific multiple cells in separate sheets within the same workbook.The below code is the code we use, and it works. So we use this private sub in one worksheet and use it the other way in the worksheet we want to link it with. The code works, but it makes the workbook slow and we would like to do it for even more sheets. So we were wondering if there was a way to make this shorter and more efficient.

Many thanks in advance

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("J3:J55", "K3:K55")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("Plan").Range("B3").Value = Range("J3").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("C3").Value = Range("K3").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("P3").Value = Range("J4").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("Q3").Value = Range("K4").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AD3").Value = Range("J5").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AE3").Value = Range("K5").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AR3").Value = Range("J6").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AS3").Value = Range("K6").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("B12").Value = Range("J7").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("C12").Value = Range("K7").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("P12").Value = Range("J8").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("Q12").Value = Range("K8").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AD12").Value = Range("J9").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AE12").Value = Range("K9").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AR12").Value = Range("J10").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AS12").Value = Range("K10").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("B21").Value = Range("J11").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("C21").Value = Range("K11").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("P21").Value = Range("J12").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("Q21").Value = Range("K12").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AD21").Value = Range("J13").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AE21").Value = Range("K13").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AR21").Value = Range("J14").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AS21").Value = Range("K14").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("B30").Value = Range("J15").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("C30").Value = Range("K15").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("P30").Value = Range("J16").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("Q30").Value = Range("K16").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AD30").Value = Range("J17").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AE30").Value = Range("K17").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AR30").Value = Range("J18").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AS30").Value = Range("K18").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("B39").Value = Range("J19").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("C39").Value = Range("K19").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("P39").Value = Range("J20").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("Q39").Value = Range("K20").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AD39").Value = Range("J21").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AE39").Value = Range("K21").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AR39").Value = Range("J22").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AS39").Value = Range("K22").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("B48").Value = Range("J23").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("C48").Value = Range("K23").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("P48").Value = Range("J24").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("Q48").Value = Range("K24").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AD48").Value = Range("J25").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AE48").Value = Range("K25").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AR48").Value = Range("J26").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AS48").Value = Range("K26").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("B57").Value = Range("J27").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("C57").Value = Range("K27").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("P57").Value = Range("J28").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("Q57").Value = Range("K28").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AD57").Value = Range("J29").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AE57").Value = Range("K29").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AR57").Value = Range("J30").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AS57").Value = Range("K30").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("B66").Value = Range("J31").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("C66").Value = Range("K31").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("P66").Value = Range("J32").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("Q66").Value = Range("K32").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AD66").Value = Range("J33").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AE66").Value = Range("K33").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AR66").Value = Range("J34").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AS66").Value = Range("K34").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("B75").Value = Range("J35").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("C75").Value = Range("K35").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("P75").Value = Range("J36").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("Q75").Value = Range("K36").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AD75").Value = Range("J37").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AE75").Value = Range("K37").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AR75").Value = Range("J38").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AS75").Value = Range("K38").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("B84").Value = Range("J39").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("C84").Value = Range("K39").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("P84").Value = Range("J40").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("Q84").Value = Range("K40").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AD84").Value = Range("J41").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AE84").Value = Range("K41").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AR84").Value = Range("J42").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AS84").Value = Range("K42").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("B93").Value = Range("J43").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("C93").Value = Range("K43").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("P93").Value = Range("J44").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("Q93").Value = Range("K44").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AD93").Value = Range("J45").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AE93").Value = Range("K45").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AR93").Value = Range("J46").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AS93").Value = Range("K46").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("B102").Value = Range("J47").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("C102").Value = Range("K47").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("P102").Value = Range("J48").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("Q102").Value = Range("K48").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AD102").Value = Range("J49").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AE102").Value = Range("K49").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AR102").Value = Range("J50").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AS102").Value = Range("K50").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("B111").Value = Range("J51").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("C111").Value = Range("K51").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("P111").Value = Range("J52").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("Q111").Value = Range("K52").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AD111").Value = Range("J53").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AE111").Value = Range("K53").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AR111").Value = Range("J54").Value
    Sheets("Plan").Range("AS111").Value = Range("K54").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The code written above works, but it makes the workbook slow and we would like to do it for even more sheets. So we were wondering if there was a way to make this shorter and more efficient.

Comment: So 9 rows and 12 columns apart in the `Plan` sheet against two columns of figures in the `Activesheet`.  Do you change one figure at a time or paste in multiple values?  i.e. How many cells would `Target` in the worksheet change event reference?

Comment: Hi Darren, thank you for your response.
We change one figure at a time. So if we want to put a value in J3 of the Active sheet, we want it to change the value to the same in B3 of the Plan sheet and the other way around. etc.

Comment: Why don't you put a simple formula into the destination cells, referencing the corresponding source cell?

Comment: If I'm reading it right, they want a 2-way change-system. If something changes in `Sheets("Plan").Range("B3")` then J3 needs to change in the other one and vice versa which you can't do with the formula @FunThomas

Comment: @Notus_Panda hadn't spotted that.  Good point.  Definitely a pattern there but my maths isn't good enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Identify the pattern and then calculate to target row. Get the target column from using an array. For a random pattern I would create a hidden sheet with 2 columns for source, target cell addresses and create a dictionary to map them.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, x As Long
    Dim cols, arData, t0 As Single

    On Error GoTo MyErrHandler
    If Intersect(Target, Range("J3:J55", "K3:K55")) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        t0 = Timer
        cols = Array("B", "P", "AD", "AR")
        arData = Range("J3:K54")
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For i = 0 To 12
            x = 3 + i * 9 '3,12,21,30 .. 111
            For j = 0 To 3 'B,P,AD,AR
                 k = k + 1
                 'Debug.Print k, cols(j), x
                 With Sheets("Plan")
                     .Cells(x, cols(j)) = arData(k, 1)
                     .Cells(x, cols(j)).Offset(, 1) = arData(k, 2)
                 End With
             Next
        Next
        MsgBox "Updated in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.000 secs"), vbInformation
    End If
MyErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Run this once to create mapping sheet

```vb
Sub createTable()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, r As Long
    Dim cols, i As Long, k As Long, x As Long, j As Long
    
    cols = Array("B", "P", "AD", "AR") 
    Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "Mapping"
    r = 1
    For i = 0 To 12
        x = 3 + i * 9 '3,12,21,30 .. 111
        For j = 0 To 3 'B,P,AD,AR
             'Debug.Print k, cols(j), x
             With ws
                 k = k + 1
                 Set rng = Range(cols(j) & x)
                 .Cells(r, 1) = "J" & k + 2
                 .Cells(r, 2) = rng.Address(0, 0)
                 .Cells(r + 1, 1) = "K" & k + 2
                 .Cells(r + 1, 2) = rng.Offset(, 1).Address(0, 0)
                 r = r + 2
             End With
         Next
    Next
End Sub
```

and then the change routine become simply

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim arMap, i As Long, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer

    On Error GoTo MyErrHandler
    If Intersect(Target, Range("J3:J55", "K3:K55")) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        arMap = Sheets("Mapping").UsedRange
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Sheets("Plan")
            For i = 1 To UBound(arMap)
               ' reverse this line for Plan sheet change
               .Range(arMap(i, 2)).Value = Range(arMap(i, 1)).Value 
            Next
        End With
        MsgBox "Updated in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.000 secs"), vbInformation
    End If
MyErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to transpose horizontal cells into a vertical column, so you can do it easily with this code:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

But seems your reference cells are not sequential like ***B1 C1 D1 E1***

so you can define an array containing all reference cell addresses, and target areas, then try to create a for loop to finish your task with an efficient method:

```
Option Base 1
 Sub vba_array_loop()
   
 Dim source_array(5) As Integer
 source_array(1) = Sheets("Plan").Range("C3").Value 
 source_array(2) = Sheets("Plan").Range("P3").Value 
 source_array(3) = Sheets("Plan").Range("Q3").Value 
 source_array(4) = Sheets("Plan").Range("AD3").Value
 source_array(5) = Sheets("Plan").Range("AE3").Value

 Dim target_array(5) As Integer
 target_array(1) = Range("K3").Value
 target_array(2) = Range("J4").Value
 target_array(3) = Range("K4").Value
 target_array(4) = Range("J5").Value
 target_array(5) = Range("K5").Value

 Dim uB As Integer, lB As Integer
 uB = UBound(source_array)
 lB = LBound(target_array)

 For i = lB To uB
    target_array(i) = source_array(i)
 Next i
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only updating one value at a time, there's no need for all of them to get updated. Hence why I calculate the row that needs to get the corresponding Cell's value and depending on J/K or B/C etc. use an Offset.

For the Test sheet (the non-"Plan" sheet):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("J3:J55", "K3:K55")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim i As Long, tRow As Long, dRow As Long, cOffset As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Me.Parent.Worksheets("Plan")
    tRow = Target.Row
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("K:K")) Is Nothing Then cOffset = 1
    i = tRow Mod 4
    dRow = ((tRow - i) / 4 - IIf(i = 3, 0, 1)) * 9 + 3
    Select Case i
        Case 3
            ws.Range("B" & dRow).Offset(, cOffset).Value = Target.Value
        Case 0
            ws.Range("P" & dRow).Offset(, cOffset).Value = Target.Value
        Case 1
            ws.Range("AD" & dRow).Offset(, cOffset).Value = Target.Value
        Case 2
            ws.Range("AR" & dRow).Offset(, cOffset).Value = Target.Value
    End Select
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The dRow (destination row) calculation seems ugly but it works from what I could see in my testing.

As for the Plan sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Union(Me.Range("B3:C111", "P3:Q111"), Me.Range("AD3:AE111", "AR3:AS111"))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim i As Long, tRow As Long, dRow As Long, cOffset As Long
    tRow = Target.Row
    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Me.Range("C3:C111"), Me.Range("Q3:Q111"), Me.Range("AE3:AE111"), Me.Range("AS3:AS111"))) Is Nothing Then cOffset = 1
    
    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 2, 3
            i = 0
        Case 16, 17
            i = 1
        Case 30, 31
            i = 2
        Case 44, 45
            i = 3
    End Select
    
    dRow = (tRow - (tRow Mod 9)) / 9 * 4 + 3 + i
    
    Me.Parent.Worksheets("Test").Cells(dRow, "J").Offset(, cOffset).Value = Target.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If it were me, I'd opt for CDP's solution with the mapping however, it'll be a lot easier to add to it if your sheet becomes bigger. Only thing I don't agree with is updating everything instead of the one cell but that's an easy fix.